# ReactJS - Setting state with multiple JSON-objects, keeps returning undefined/non-changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to set the state with the objects in **getMatchesByDogId**. But Res1 & Res2 keeps returning *undefined*, and the state only returns the values from initialState (unchanged).

I will be getting data from DB through axios later, and the format looks like this:

> {
> "body": {
> "id": 5,
> "name": "Enya",
> "gender": "Female"
> "user": {
> "id": 3,
> "firstName": "Tim"
> }
> }
> }

I thought that I might be getting the path wrong when assigned the data in **name: res.name**, so I tried **name: res.body.name**, **name: res.data.body.name** - But none of these solutions were successful.
I have researched, although I'm obviously searching for the wrong information.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Matching extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getMatchesByDogId = this.getMatchesByDogId.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            items: [
                this.initialState
            ]
        }
    };

        initialState = {
            body: {
                name: "Initial",
                gender: "Initial",
                user: {
                    id: "Initial",
                    firstName: "Initial"
                }
            }
        }

    async getMatchesByDogId(){

                const dummyData = [
                    {body: {name: "Enya", gender: "Female",
                            user: {id: 1, firstName: "Tim"}}
                    },
                    {body: {name: "Fido", gender: "Male",
                            user: {id: 1, firstName: "Steve"}}
                    },
                    {body: {name: "Spike", gender: "Male",
                            user: {id: 2, firstName: "Dude"}}
                    },
                    {body: {name: "Lassie", gender: "Female",
                            user: {id: 3, firstName: "Lisa"}}
                    }
                ]

                return dummyData;
    }

    async componentDidMount() {

    console.log("Res1: ", res.data)

        this.getMatchesByDogId().then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                    body : {
                        name: res.name,
                        gender: res.gender,
                        user: {
                            id: res.id,
                            firstName: res.firstName
                        }
                    }
            });

      console.log("Res2: ", res.name)

        })

      console.log("State: ", this.state);

    };
}
```

Comment: You're returning an array, but then keying into it like it's an object. You need to pick an item from the array, then index into it, e.g. `res[0].body.name`. You can plop your structure (after calling `JSON.stringify()` on it) into [this tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68460317/6243352) and navigate it to get the path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getMatchesByDogId method is returning an array not a single entry. If you want to add the array to your state you can just do something like the following

```js
  this.getMatchesByDogId().then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                    items: res
            });
```

Since you're just returning the array there's also no res.data prop. This prop is only part of axios response (https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema)